# Pandas dataframe incomplete output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[image]

I have a dataframe where one column has multiline text like shown in the screenshot.
However, when i extract the contents of that cell, i see only first line. Is there anything wrong that i am doing ? Please help. Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you `print(X)`?

Comment: I did both.. print and without print

Comment: to_list() and then print?

Comment: to_list() fetches the entire output... and its all in just single element of the list.
Thank you.. But i am curious as to why string method didn't work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to_list() and then print? –
Marco Cerliani
May 16 2020 at 18:52

Comment: It should be in comment As this is not an answer.